# How to listen to model in angularjs using controller as syntax?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i don't know how to listen property of controller through the $scope

http://codepen.io/Tek/pen/fgIkG/ - controller as syntax

http://codepen.io/Tek/pen/zqCpF /?editors=111 - $scope

Comment: Paste some code here. Also, be clear about the issue that you face and the solution that you are expecting. Put in as many details as possible. I am not sure if it is only for me, but I can't seem to access the links

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$scope` and not `this` inside a controller to bind values.

[Here's the edited code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BcDdh)
And I believe you were going for [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LJgzo/).

Comment: in your example "controller as syntax" - becomes are useless

Answer (score 0):

In the newest version of `Angular JS` i.e, `1.2` they have introduces a new keyword `controllerAs` to make it possible not to have scope inside a controller.

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl as test">
    {{test.value}}
</div>
```

And in your controller

```
app.controller('testCtrl ', function () {
   this.value = 'Hello World';
});
```

See the above controller is generated with out injecting `$scope` in it.

[Here](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-experimental-controller-as-synta) is a good video tutorial explaining this

Comment: i know, but  how listen inside controller scope changes?